# How do I download multiple files or an entire folder from Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

Currently, I can download files as individual files with the command

```
files.download(file_name)
```

I also tried uploading them to the drive with the below code snippet but it is uploading them as individual files.

```
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': file_name})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))
```

How can I download multiple files as a folder to my local computer? Or how can I upload these files as a folder to my google drive?

Answer (score 373):

I have created a zip file:

```
!zip -r /content/file.zip /content/Folder_To_Zip
```

Than I have downloded that zip file:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("/content/file.zip")
```

Comment: It is also worth noting, if you have problems downloading a large file over `files.download()`, you may also click on the chevron-right icon at the top left corner and browse all files under the `Files` tab and manually download the file.

Comment: If you ask: "Where is file.zip?" you could find it at the bottom on the left pane of the Colab Notebook. Then you could download it by right-clicking on it.

Comment: my filename is in python . . . how do you translate my python code into that format

Comment: For me for some reason it stuck on `files.download`(.zip size ~2mb), but I was able to download it via `Files` manually.

Answer (score 36):

For example, if you have to download log folder:

`!zip -r log.zip log/`

`-r` represent recursive

while `log.zip` is destination zip file and
`log/`   is source folder path

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I found that:

```
!zip -r ./myresultingzippedfolderwithallthefiles.zip ./myoriginalfolderwithallthefiles/
```

worked for me in colab.

Here `.` can be your home directory or the directory where your original `myoriginalfolderwithallthefiles` is and where `myresultingzippedfolderwithallthefiles.zip` will be created. Change the directories as needed.

Answer (score 11):

```
!zip -r /content/sample_data.zip /content/sample_data
# change sample_data.zip to your desired download name Ex: nothing.zip
# change sample_data to your desired download folder name Ex: ner_data
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to download an entire folder containing h5 files(for submitting a college project) of each model my notebook built. Easiest way I found to download this folder and hence all files in the folder is to **drag and drop the folder into the "My Drive" folder in the same folder tree.**

[image: Drive folder and folder to be uploaded highlighted]

Obviously I later downloaded the folder from Google Drive.

Answer (score 6):

You may use code to zip folders and download them using `files`.

```
#@title Utility to zip and download a directory
#@markdown Use this method to zip and download a directory. For ex. a TB logs 
#@markdown directory or a checkpoint(s) directory.

from google.colab import files
import os

dir_to_zip = 'dir_name' #@param {type: "string"}
output_filename = 'file.zip' #@param {type: "string"}
delete_dir_after_download = "No"  #@param ['Yes', 'No']

os.system( "zip -r {} {}".format( output_filename , dir_to_zip ) )

if delete_dir_after_download == "Yes":
    os.system( "rm -r {}".format( dir_to_zip ) )

files.download( output_filename )
```

Comment: If you don't have a folder of files and everything is on the main directory of Colab, you can use 

```dir_to_zip = '/content' #@param {type: "string"}``` for the above code.

That is the main dir of Colab.

Comment: Another question: How can I select a few files to zip? All my files are on the main dir and I only need to zip 4 of them. How can I specifically zip just those?

Answer (score 4):

Copy this code into a cell, and change the 2 fields filename and folders_or_files_to_save.
It will zip all of the folders or files into a zipfile and save it in your Google drive

```
#@title save yo data to drive
filename = "kerasmodel" #@param {type:"string"}
folders_or_files_to_save = "keras_model.h5" #@param {type:"string"}
from google.colab import files
from google.colab import auth
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def save_file_to_drive(name, path):
    file_metadata = {
    'name': name,
    'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload(path, 
                  mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                  resumable=True)

    created = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

    print('File ID: {}'.format(created.get('id')))

    return created


extension_zip = ".zip"

zip_file = filename + extension_zip

# !rm -rf $zip_file
!zip -r $zip_file {folders_or_files_to_save} # FOLDERS TO SAVE INTO ZIP FILE

auth.authenticate_user()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

destination_name = zip_file
path_to_file = zip_file
save_file_to_drive(destination_name, path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tar` to group files in a directory into a single file.

For example, here's a snippet that creates a directory, 3 files inside it, and a `.tar` archive containing the group:

```
!mkdir demo
!echo a > demo/a
!echo b > demo/b
!echo c > demo/c
!tar -cvf demo.tar demo/
```

The file to download would be `demo.tar` in this case. For more tips, search for creating and expanding tar archives.

Answer (score 1):

Use the copy path for the folder which you want to download. Then:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("path")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me with low latency:

Step 1: Mount the google drive.

Step 2: Zip the content.

```
!zip -r destination_path_to_zip_file.zip source_path_to_zip
```

Step 3: Copy the zip file to the google drive.

```
!cp source destination
```

Step 4: Download the file.

Answer (score -1):

1. If Drive and Colab Notebook both are your private:

   - a) Mount the Drive,
   - b) travers the path to your folder, click on "..." in front of the file name and use the path to the file/folder
2. If You want to download a special folder **without mounting Drive**:

   - a) make a **zip file** of your folder (for single file no need for zipping)
   - b) `!gdown --id zip_file_id 'like this id 1ZxqBjXlF0H6.....'`
   - c) for file_id

     1-- -----use Get Link or Share of your ziped file ---
     [image]
     2-- -------ID part of your file share link-------

[image]

Comment: not clearly defined. please write proper answers and not shortcuts.